# MD5 output different after the first round

Tags: c, hex, md5

I am testing the MD5 algorithm, and the code is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *msg;
    size_t len;
    int i;
    uint8_t result[16];

    uint8_t buf[16];
    msg = "md5_5_times";
    len = strlen(msg);
    md5((uint8_t*)msg, len, result);

    // display result
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        printf("%2.2x", result[i]);
    puts("");

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        memmove(buf, result, 16);
        md5((uint8_t*)buf, 16, result);
        memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            printf("%2.2x", result[j]);
        puts("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the first round is the same as the result of an online MD5 calculator. However, the output of the four rounds in the for loop is different. I suspect that the reason is that the input data in the for loop is a hex string, while the input data in the first round is an ASCII string.

How can I modify the code to fix this issue?

hash result:

```
7e9dbd24e91a4575a1d176ef0d370579
...
44fd5a924a76097b23511cae0774de56
2e7e0b54e065fe5e29a77ccb415ae2ee
797f5799a539a18a8369da5fd23ea71c
```

Comment: The input data in the for loop is not a hex string (32 bytes), it is 16 bytes. Are you checking for correctness by calculating a MD5 hash over the hex representation? You can repeatedly calculate MD5 hashes online here: https://cryptii.com/pipes/md5-hash

Comment: OT: You can use `memcpy` instead of `memmove` when buffers are disjoint. The call to `memset` does not serve any purpose.

Comment: @rocky Detail: "while the input data in the first round is an ASCII string." --> Not quite a _string_.  With `len = strlen(msg); md5((uint8_t*)msg, len, result);`, `md5()` does not process the _null character_ in `msg`.  Same result expected with `char msg[11] = "md5_5_times";  md5((uint8_t*)msg, 11, result);`.  In this case, `msg` is not a _string_ as it lacks a _null character_.

Comment: @rocky "However, the output of the four rounds in the for loop is different."  --> Post the _exact_ input used for the online MD5 calculator.  Was it 16 bytes like your code?

Comment: @rocky "input data in the for loop is a hex string" --> In the posted code, the input used is not a _hex string_ of 32 characters, but an array of 16 bytes.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I understand. I appreciate your answer.